# UPDATE таблицы из одной базы данных в таблицу другой базы данных

Tags: mysql, update

Доброго времени суток, товарищи!
Прошу посоветовать как лучше сделать.
Цель - **обновить** данные из одной таблицы в другую.
Структура таблиц **идентична**.
БД на разных серверах.
Кусок кода

```
$mysqli = connect_db();

    $result = $mysqli->query("
    SELECT 
      r1, r2, r3, r4 и т.д.
    FROM 
      table_one
    WHERE 
      result <='3' AND
      state = 'disabled'
    ORDER BY
      reverse (r3) 
    LIMIT 
      1000");
```

Этот запрос я беру из базы. Но не могу разобраться как после `SELECT` сделать `UPDATE` нужной информации.

И еще вопрос как правильно сделать так, чтобы объём запроса на обновление не положил базу данных на долго?
Теперь у меня тупик с `implode(', ' $result);`

```
$result
```

это массив полученный `SELECT`ом из БД. Вызываю `implode();` он дает только часть массива до первого разделителя.
Как мне получить весь массив?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого удобно воспользоваться запросом `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` при помощи которого вы можете перегнать данные из одной таблицы в другую. Так как у вас таблицы находятся в разных базах данных, то лучше всего воспользоваться расширенной нотацией, указав перед именами таблиц явно названия баз данных. В этом случае вы не будете зависеть в запросе от текущей базы данных.

Новые записи вставятся в таблицу, для того, чтобы обновить существующие данные в запрос следует добавить ключевое слово `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, утверждения в котором сработают в том случае, если в таблице уже имеется запись со вставляемым первичным ключом. В этом случае, следует обновить уже существующие значения, так как это показано в примере ниже.

В следующем запросе, данные из таблицы `table_one` базы данных `currdb` перегоняются в одноименную таблицу базу данных `otherdb`.

```
<?php
...
$query = "INSERT INTO
            otherdb.table_one
          SELECT 
            r1, r2, r3, r4
          FROM 
            currdb.table_one
          WHERE 
            result <= '3' 
          AND
            state = 'disabled'
          ORDER BY
            reverse (r3) 
          LIMIT 
            1000
          ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
            r1 = VALUES(r1),
            r2 = VALUES(r2),
            r3 = VALUES(r3),
            r4 = VALUES(r4)";

$result = $mysqli->query($query);
```

В конструкции `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` придется перечислить все столбцы, которые вы хотите обновить.

Для того, чтобы не заблокировать таблицы на долго, уменьшайте количество записей в конструкции `LIMIT` и обновляйте данные в несколько приемов.

Если базы данных у вас расположены на разных серверах, тогда придется сначала извлечь SELECT-запросом данные с первого сервера, а потом сформировать многострочный INSERT-запрос ко второму серверу. Здесь так же можно воспользоваться конструкцией `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, для того, чтобы обновлять уже существующие данные

```
<?php
// Устанавливаем соединение с первой базой данных
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Ошибка подключения (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

// Извлекаем записи из таблицы первой базы данных
$query = "SELECT
            *
          FROM
            table_one
          WHERE
            result <= '3'
          AND
            state = 'disabled'
          ORDER BY
            reverse (r3)
          LIMIT
            1000";

if(!$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
    die('Ошибка выполнения запроса (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $balans);
$sql = array();
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
  $r1 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($r1);
  $r2 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($r2);
  $r3 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($r3);
  $r4 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($r4);
  $sql[] = "('$id', '$r1', '$r2', '$r3', '$r4')";
}
$mysqli->close();

// Устанавливаем соединение со второй базой данных
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'balans');

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Ошибка подключения (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

if(count($sql) > 0) {
  $query = "INSERT INTO balans VALUES "
           . implode(',', $sql) .
           " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
              r1 = VALUES(r1),
              r2 = VALUES(r2),
              r3 = VALUES(r3),
              r4 = VALUES(r4)";
  $mysqli->query($query);
}
$mysqli->close();
```

У этого способа имеется одно ограничение, размер SQL-запроса, который вы направляете серверу не должен превышать размер заданный параметром `max_allowed_packet` (нужно либо увеличить размер этой директивы, либо уменьшить количество записей в `LIMIT`).

Плюс, если это не разовая, а переодическая операция, следует рассмотреть штатный механизм репликации, который перегонит данные гораздо быстрее и точнее, чем это будет в любой PHP-реализации.

Comment: Подскажите пример для работы с 2 БД.  
Я знаю как работать с 1 подключением :   
`function connect_db() {
  $mysqli_function = new mysqli (
     "localhost",
     "root",
     "",
     "db"
     );
  return $mysqli_function;
 }`  
После делаю   `SELECT` нужных полей, а вот `INSERT`   нужно сделать в другую  БД на другом сервере.

Comment: @Евгений дополнил ответ